# Proving non CFL with pumping lemma

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I can't seem to figure out how to prove this as not a CFL:

$$\left\{x^{a}y^{b}\mid a=kb\space\text{for some positive integer k}\right\}$$

I've tried a bunch of "s"'s to pump such as $a^{2p}b^{p}$ but everything seems to be able to be pumped. Could anyone give me a hint on how to continue this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, start with the word $w=a^{p(p+1)}b^{p+1}$. It decomposes as $w=uvxyz$, where $|vxy|\le p$, $|vy|\ge 1$, and $uv^kxy^kz\in L$ for all $k\ge 0$. Let $n=|vxy|\le p$; then $vxy=a^rb^{n-r}$ for some $r$ such that $0\le r\le n$. Note that this is enough to guarantee that $r\ne p(n-r)$, since $n\le p$. Use this to show that pumping $w$ down to $uxz$ must then give you a word not in $L$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now why this would be a contradiction if $r$ is not 0 or $n$, but lets say $vxy$ is all $a$'s, how do we know that $v^{k}xy^{k}$ $k$>0 can never be a multiple of $p+1$ and thus be in $L$ and able to be pumped?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it, if that means anything....

Comment: @Matt: You don’t need to know that $uv^kxy^kz$ is **never** in $L$: to prove that $L$ is not context-free, you need only show that there is **at least one** $k\ge0$ such that $uv^kxy^kz\notin L$, and $k=0$ works.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: @Matt: You’re welcome.